# Can I export a material change in an animation in glb format?

Tags: animation, materials

In my animation, I want an object to change from grey to red. I can do this in blender by keyframing the base color, but when I export to a .glb, the color change does not appear and the object stays grey. Does anyone know how this can be animated and seen in .glb format? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Blender manual (as I was having the same trouble).

*"Animation of other properties, like lights or materials, will be ignored."*

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

full paragraph below:

*Animation
glTF allows multiple animations per file, with animations targeted to particular objects at time of export. To ensure that an animation is included, either (a) make it the active Action on the object, (b) create a single-strip NLA track, or (c) stash the action.
Supported
Only certain types of animation are supported:

- Keyframe (translation, rotation, scale)
- Shape keys
- Armatures / skinning

Animation of other properties, like lights or materials, will be ignored.*